# How does lme4 handle participants who only have data for only one level of a categorial variable

Tags: lme4-nlme, missing-data

I'm using the lme4 package to assess the impact of a variable 'A,' which consists of three levels (1, 2, and 3), on the responses of 15 participants. My model is structured as follows:

```
m <- lmer(response ~ A + (A|participant))
```

Following the model fitting process, I realized that one of the participants only has data for Level 1 of variable 'A', but not for the other two levels. Unsurprisingly, this issue doesn't trigger any warnings because my dataset is organized in such a way that each row represents a response, ensuring there are no NAs in the dataset.

I'm interested in understanding how lme4 handles this specific participant, especially in the context of estimating random slopes. Should I retain this participant's data in the dataset and rely on the model estimates, or would it be advisable to exclude their data altogether and re-run the model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all OK; in general you should keep all of the data for such analyses — it's one of the advantages of modern mixed-model frameworks (in contrast to older sums-of-squares-partitioning methods, which work poorly with unbalanced data).

Individuals for whom only a subset of levels is measured will contribute information to the estimates of among-group variation for the measured levels (and contrasts/differences among them), but not (naturally) to the estimates for the unmeasured level. The shrinkage estimator, which weights combinations of estimates based on their uncertainty, takes care of everything; unmeasured quantities are shrunk to the population level.

Comment: I'd be curious if you have any references that support the statement that mixed models perform better than classic regression in respect to unbalanced groups in the model fit. I have previously read that unbalanced or small random effects clusters will bias some of the estimates, but am not educated on how this works for the fixed effects.

Comment: TBH I'm going on the fact that books on ANOVA that I've read (e.g. Underwood's *Experiments in Ecology*) discuss the effects of lack of balance in some detail, whereas AFAICT there's nothing in the setup of modern mixed model solutions that depends on balance in any way ... ?  But maybe this *only* about the foofaraw around sums of squares, marginality etc. and not actually about estimation? e.g. https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1365-2656.2009.01634.x

Comment: Thank you for the response, Ben. Could you please confirm my understanding of the following two points? 1) We should retain this participant's data during modeling, even though this individual has data for only one of the levels; 2) We can have confidence in the model estimates. After calling 'ranef()', the slopes for this participant do indeed appear in the output. We can trust these estimates, right?

Comment: Yes and yes ....